# Using SELinux to force Linux to allow programs to bind to port numbers lower than 1024

Tags: permissions, port, selinux

Is there a way in SELinux to force linux to allow a program to be able to bind to a port number lower than 1024.

Comment: Capabilities allow that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-li Of course, selinux may then prevent it in which case you can fiddle with making an selinux policy.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a proper policy module for the application (let's call your app "foo") in place, you can do one of two things. You either define a `foo_port_t` type in the policy, allow you4 app access to it, like this:

```
allow foo_t foo_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

and the use something like this to label the actual port

```
semanage port -a -t foo_port_t -p tcp 803
```

This will claim TCP port 803 for your application. Most ports below 1023 already have labels on them though and you cannot label a port, file, whatever multiple times.

So option two: you can allow your app to bind to a port that has a different label, by putting lines like this into your policy module:

```
require { 
    type http_port_t;
}

allow foo_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

This would allow you app to bind to any port that has `http_port_t` (meaning 80, 443, 488, 8008, 8009 and 8443). You can find what label the port (803 in this example) you want to use, has by this command:

```
semanage port -l | grep 803
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it as root or `sudo` it. You should only use root for testing, never in production. The kernel won't allow you to open a port below 1024 (well-known ports) without these permissions. It has nothing to do with SELinux but with the kernel.

Comment: You should never run processes as root if you can help it. This could lead to a much larger security issue than shutting down SELinux

Comment: @Mike: Unless it's written to explicitly drop root privileges after startup.

Comment: However if the process forks before it drops the root privileges, then you still have a security issue. Also what is the process going to do before it drops its privileges. Can you guarantee that it is going to do what you want? You are best to never run anything as the root user because you never know what the service is capable of.

Comment: SELinux is very capable of blocking attempts of confined applications to bind to privileged ports. Yes, it can be the kernel, but it can be SELinux as well.

Comment: As an addendum on this point, you actually only need the binding program to have `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` which is given its own capability to address the exact concern that you have with running a network program run as root

Answer (score 1):

It is not SELinux that does not allow your program to bind on privileged ports, it is the Linux kernel. More precisely `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` [capability](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/capabilities).

You can do a port forwarding from the desired port to an unprivileged port and run the application on an unprivileged port. This is secure and allowed by SELinux.

[Docker 20.3](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41030/files) updates kernel unprivileged port range to start at 0, as opposed to the default 1024. In this way `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` is not required anymore to bind to ports less than 1024.

Comment: While it doesn't directly answer the OP's question, I think it's really what they want to achieve - the server (through a firewall rule) accepts connections at the low-numbered port and forwards to the internal high-numbered port that the unprivileged user account can use. It's a lot simpler than disabling stuff that should be left alone.

Comment: Hi John. Thank you. I've updated the answer to reflect recent changes in Docker.

Answer (score -3):

In our shop and experience, we have found it best to disable SELinux. I know that some people have found it useful but we have not.

We disable the entire thing in /etc/sysconfig/selinux (or /etc/selinux/config) with SELINUX=disabled

The problems we have had regarding SELinux have been so numerous and caused so many extra hours that it is just not worth it.

Comment: These days, I recommend in Production to NOT disable SELinux due to security concerns. With RHEL, etc. now enable SELinux by default and it should not be disable so you have a new layer of protection.